# Pipe catch error, navigation redirect fails

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

To load a single image using route params, I call my backend to search for products by id, if it hasn't been loaded yet.

This works if there's a product with the given id, but returns an error if the user somehow manipulates the url and the id is invalid. To handle this issue I create a not-found component the user shall be redirected to.

I can catch this error by using `catchError`. But calling `router.navigate` inside fails. How so?

> Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  product: Product;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private dataService: VideosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        map(paramsMap => paramsMap.get('id')),
        switchMap(id => this.dataService.getVideoById(id)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      ).subscribe((value: Product) => {
        this.product = value[0];
    });
  }

  handleError() {
    this.router.navigate(['/not-found']);
    return throwError('Could not find matching products. Redirecting...')
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to either use arrow function notation `catchError(() => this.handleError())` or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function `catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))` to denote to the error hanlder that `this` keyword points to the class scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **catchError** requires a function as argument.

```
ngOnInit(): void {  
         this.route.paramMap
          .pipe(
            map(paramsMap => paramsMap.get('id')),
            switchMap(id => this.dataService.getVideoById(id)),
            catchError(() => this.handleError())
          ).subscribe((value: Product) => {
            this.product = value[0];
        });
    }
```

Refer [this](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) for more detail information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntactic error. If you're using `catchError(this.handleError)`, `handeError` has to be an arrow function to pass the `this` context to your `handleError` when it's being called in the `catchError`. So convert the function to an arrow function like so:

```
handleError = () => {
  this.router.navigate(['/not-found']);
  return throwError('Could not find matching products. Redirecting...')
}
```